# Algebraic groups and restricted Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

If $G$ is an algebraic group with coordinate algebra $A=\mathcal O(G)$, say over a field $k$ of characteristic $p$, then its Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ can be endowed with the structure of a *restricted Lie algebra* by defining a $p$-operation $\mathfrak g\to\mathfrak g$ via the inclusion
$$ \mathfrak g \to \mathrm{Der}_k(A,A), $$
and using $p$-th power maps: the $p$-operation is simply the $p$-th power in $\mathrm{Hom}_k(A,A)$ which, as it turns out, sends left-invariant derivations to left-invariant derivations, i.e. maps $\mathfrak g$ into itself.

However, $\mathfrak g$ can also be thought of as the vector space $\mathrm{Der}_k(A,k_1)$, where $k_1$ is $k$ as an $A$-module through the identity $1\in G$ (which is a map $A\to k$ with kernel $\mathfrak m$) or as a vector space $\mathrm{Hom}_k(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2,k)$.

My question: is it possible to define the $p$-operation *directly* on $\mathrm{Der}_k(A,k_1)$? In fact, every alternative way to introduce and study the $p$-operation would be kindly appreciated especially those most easily expressed in the scheme-theoretic language for algebraic groups.

Answer (score 1):

A remark - we can also define the $p$-operation directly on the Lie algebra as follows (Jacobson proved that this is equivalent with being the restricted Lie algebra of an algebraic group).

A restricted $p$-Lie algebra is a Lie algebra $L$ over a field $K$ together
with a $p$-map
$[p]\colon \mathfrak{g}
\to \mathfrak{g},\;x \mapsto x^{[p]}$, such that

$(1)$ ${\rm ad} \:x^{[p]}=(ad \:x)^p \quad \forall \;x \in \mathfrak{g}$

$(2)$ $(\alpha x)^{[p]}=\alpha^p x^{[p]} \quad \forall \;x \in \mathfrak{g},\;\alpha \in K$

$(3)$ $ad \:(x+y)^{[p]}=x^{[p]}+y^{[p]}+\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} s_i(x,y)$,
where $i\:s_i(x,y)$ is the coefficient of $X^{i-1}$ in the polynomial $(ad \,(xX+y))
^{p-1}(x)$.

Comment: I may misunderstand you but don't think you can define _the_ p-operation by these properties; rather they define _any_ p-operation. So to be precise, these are properties that the operation $x\mapsto x^p$ on an associative algebra $A$ has which can be expressed directly in terms of the Lie bracket. So Jacobson abstracted those properties and called any Lie algebra with such an operation a restricted Lie algebra. The main point being that a priori, these properties need not uniquely determine the $p$-operation as far as I know. Does that sound correct?

Comment: On the other hand, I just realised if $\mathfrak g\to\mathrm{End}(\mathfrak g) : x\mapsto \mathrm{ad}(x)$ is injective (i.e. when the center of $\mathfrak g$ is trivial), then the first property already defines $x^{[p]}$ uniquely. So that's interesting...

Comment: Yes, if the center of $L$ is trivial, one can omit $(3)$, and there exists at most one $p$-operation. In general, there may be more $p$-operations (or none), but the existence means that $L$ is the Lie algebra of an algebraic group.